# Left join FROM multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, syntax, left-join

This question is different than the ones I have seen already answered. Is it possible to left join using multiple 'FROM' tables? When I try it (with other code, but the principle is the same) I get the error 'Unknown column 'table1.otherId' in 'on clause'. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1, table2
LEFT JOIN other_table
ON other_table.id = table2.id
AND other_table.otherId = table1.otherId
```

Comment: Don't use comma-join syntax, and DEFINITELY don't mix it with ANSI JOIN syntax.

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what you want to accomplish would all help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you want to do.  You seem to want a Cartesian product of the first two tables with lookups on the third:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 CROSS JOIN
     table2 LEFT JOIN
     other_table
     ON other_table.id = table2.id AND
        other_table.otherId = table1.otherId;
```

Commas -- which should just be banned permanently from `FROM` clauses -- are similar to `CROSS JOIN`s.  However, the parsing of the SQL statement is different.  A comma prevents the tables before it from being used in `ON` clauses after it; that is the source of your error.

Comment: you want to be careful before using a cross join.   cross joins are good for creating a catalog of all possible combinations between two datasets.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:-

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN other_table
ON table1.id=other_table.id LEFT JOIN table2 ON
other_table.otherId = table2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer is "No"

But you can do it this way:

```
SELECT * FROM table2, other_table ON other_table.id = table2.id
LEFT JOIN table1 ON other_table.otherId = table1.otherId
```